# Fortran 90 rank mismatch

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am quite new in Fortran, and just got the program from a PhD. It is used to count the number of beads in certain histograms. Here is the code:

```
program xrdf
    implicit none
    include 'currentconf.fi'
    real drdf,rdf12(200)
    real xni12, Zface
    integer ibead,iconf,ii,io,i,j,k,linecount
    integer mchains, iendbead, nstart
    logical ifend

    Zface=1.5
    mchains=49
    drdf=0.1
    xni12=0.
    io=10
    nstart=12636
    open(file='pcushion.tr.xmol',unit=io)
    do i=1,200
       rdf12(i)=0.0
    end do
    ifend=.false.
    do iconf=1,1000000
 ! reading current frame
       ii=iconf
       call readconf(io,ii,linecount,ifend)
       write(*,*)' conf ',iconf,' N=',n
       if (ifend) go to 777
 ! if trajectory ended, exit loop
       ibead=0

       do i=1,mchains
          iendbead=nstart+i*45
          dz=abs(Zface-z(iendbead))
          ii=int(dz/drdf)+1
          rdf12(ii)=rdf12(ii)+1
          xni12=xni12+1.0
       end do

    end do !iconf

777      write(*,*)' total ',iconf-1,' frames '
    write(*,*)' r       rho(z)     '
    do i=1,200
       write(*,'(f10.4,e15.7)')(i-0.5)*drdf,rdf12(i)/xni12
    end do
    close(io)
    stop
    end
```

Because I really do not know which part is wrong, so I just past all the code here. When I compile this program, there comes an error:

```
i=int(dz/drdf)+1
    1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

How can I edit the program to fix it?

Comment: @user814064 The PhD told me the program will automatically read this data in the pcushion.tr.xmol file. Suppose'z(10)', then the program will find the specific value from that file.

Comment: You declare `implicit none` at the start of the program which means all variables have to be declared, but I can't see where the array `z()` is declared or where `dz` is declared.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterM: my assumption is that it is contained within the `include 'currentconf.fi'` line.

Comment: @KyleKanos That would explain it, but without that missing piece of the puzzle I can only suspect that `dz` is not a scalar.

Comment: @PeterM: that is probably a good assumption.

Comment: @KyleKanos Given that the last time I looked at Fortran was about 1983, its a damn good assumption!

Comment: Show us the `currentconf.fi` file please.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your compiler error using a simple program. It seems likely that in

```
ii=int(dz/drdf)+1
```

you are trying to assign an array (maybe dz?) to an integer (ii).

```
integer ibead,iconf,ii,io,i,j,k,linecount
```

Compare the dimensions of ii (dimension is 1) with the dimensions of dz and drdf.

This is my program (compiled it using gfortran):

```
      PROGRAM TEST

      implicit none
      integer dz(10),ii
      real dy

      dz=3
      dy=2.0
      ii=int(dz/dy)+1

      END PROGRAM TEST
```

Using ifort the error message is more revealing:

```
error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform
```

Comment: It has to be `dz`, `drdf` is declared as a scalar.